# Horizontal bar charts with min and max data in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, horizontal

I am trying to create a horizontal bar chart like the one in the picture below. For that I want to use data stored in a table like this:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
system,   Tmin, Tmax, limitmin, limitmax
{a},      20,     50,     10,      30
{b},     10,     60,     15,      60
{c},      15,     78,     0,       0
```

}\datatable

[image: What I want]

The closest I came to a result was by manually typing in the coordinates. But the stacked bar chart keeps adding/ subtracting the values and I cant figure out how to let a bar start from a value different to zero.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar stacked,
stack negative=on previous ,
xlabel={Temperature $^{\circ}C$},
symbolic y coords={%
    {A},
    {B},
    {C}},
ytick=data,
%nodes near coords, 
%nodes near coords align={horizontal},
ytick=data,
xmajorgrids,
legend
]
    
\addplot+[blue, fill=blue, bar shift =-5pt] coordinates {
    (14,{A}) 
    (5,{B}) 
    (14,{C}) 
};
\addplot+[blue, fill=blue, bar shift =-5pt] coordinates {
    (-20,{A}) 
    (-10,{B}) 
    (14,{C}) 
};
\addplot+[red, fill=red, bar shift =5pt] coordinates {
    (20,{A}) 
    (5,{B}) 
    (14,{C}) 
};

\addplot+[red, fill=red, bar shift =5pt] coordinates {
    (-20,{A}) 
    (-10,{B}) 
    (14,{C}) 
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

There is probably a proper way to do this but I am still new to tikz and pgfplots and could not find a good example.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but I still cant have the minimum of a bar start at a value not equal to 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Since this question is closed, I can't post an answer. And the code is too long for a single comment.

`\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
  system,   Tmin, Tmax, limitmin, limitmax
  {a},      20,     50,     10,      30
  {b},     10,     60,     15,      60
  {c},      15,     78,     0,       0
 }{\datatable}
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xlabel=Temperature,
 xbar,
 ytick distance=1,
 enlarge x limits=0.15,
 bar width=0.8em,
 symbolic y coords={a, b, c, d, e},
 grid=both,
 ]`…

Comment: …`\addplot +[forget plot] table [x index=1, y index=0] {\datatable};
 \addplot table [x index=2, y index=0] {\datatable};
 \addlegendentry{T}
 
 \addplot +[forget plot] table [x index=3, y index=0] {\datatable};
 \addplot table [x index=4, y index=0] {\datatable};
 \addlegendentry{Limit}
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks, but the bars still start at zero instead of Tmin/ limitmin.