# How to let a bar chart start from value different to zero with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, plot, bar-chart

Following up on a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601214/horizontal-bar-charts-with-min-and-max-data-in-pgfplots). How do I let a bar chart start from a value different to zero? Including negative numbers.

As you can see when I plot the data from the table all bars start at zero.

[image]

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
system,   Tmin, Tmax, limitmin, limitmax        
{a},      20,     50,     -10,      30      
{b},     10,     60,     15,      60        
{c},      -15,     -5,     0,       10  
}{\datatable}       
\begin{tikzpicture}     
\begin{axis}[
sactter,
xlabel=Temperature,     
xbar,   
ytick distance=1,   
enlarge x limits=0.15,  
bar width=0.8em,    
symbolic y coords={a, b, c, d, e},  
grid=both,  ]

\addplot  +[forget plot] table [x index=1, y index=0] {\datatable};     
\addplot table [x index=2, y index=0] {\datatable}; 
\addlegendentry{T}   
\addplot +[forget plot] table [x index=3, y index=0] {\datatable};
\addplot table [x index=4, y index=0] {\datatable};     
\addlegendentry{Limit} 
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bar graph with positive min max](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371451/bar-graph-with-positive-min-max)

Comment: Unfortunatly not. I cant seem to get it working with my table and horizontal chart.